# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider from ProcessRecord

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

When I share image from brawser to my android application i get following image Uri
content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/1507896426215620831996.jpg

```
<activity
            android:name=".splash.SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHSCREEN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now in order to get that image I am using following function

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) throws IOException {
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                    context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
            parcelFileDescriptor.close();
            return image;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

While getting ParcelFileDescriptor from Uri getting following exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider from ProcessRecord{c57dcea 3162:com.slocamo.ucee/u0a246} (pid=3162, uid=10246) that is not exported from uid 10111

It is same case when i triend using another brawser. Any idea what is being wrong?

Comment: "When I share image from brawser to my android application" -- is this via `ACTION_SEND`, or something else? What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Yes both things are there, its SecurityException getting from  org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider

Comment: Yes its via ACTION_SEND, I am testing it on Android N, Android M

Comment: My mistake I was storing image uri in sharedpreferences and trying to fetch that image from other activity. It should be fetched from same activity. Now its working